# Loop through Checkboxes in Kendo ui-Menu on Toolbar in Kendo Grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to implement a Kendo ui-Menu in the toolbar of a Kendo Grid in Angular.  I am manually creating the column list on the menu.  I am able to show/hide the columns when clicking the checkboxes.  I need to iterate through the checkboxes when the menu opens so that I can set checked/unchecked based on the options set on each column in the grid.  The problem is that I don't know how to access the check/unchecked of the child nodes.

The code below gets all of the child nodes, but I don't know how to access their checked/unchecked values:

```
var columns = $(e.item).find(".k-item:not(:has(.k-group))");
```

I have a [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@DevQueen/iRAfEh) setup where the check/uncheck works, but I don't know how to access them from 'onOpen'.  Any assistance is grealy appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jarosław Kończak who put me on the right path, here is how I eventually was able to use the "hidden attribute" on my columns to set the checkboxes as checked or !checked by altering his suggestion just a little:

```
  $scope.onOpen = function(e) {
  var checkboxes = $(e.item).find(".k-item:not(:has(.k-group))").find("input[type='checkbox']");
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      var checkbox = $(checkboxes[i]);
      if (checkbox.prop("checked")) {
          var fieldData = checkbox.data("field");
          var columns = $scope.SearchGrid.columns;
          for (var x = 0; x < columns.length; x++) {
              if (columns[x].field == fieldData) {
                  if (columns[x].hidden == true) {
                      checkbox.prop("checked", false);
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

}

Here is a working [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@DevQueen/oDICU) with dynamically created columns instead of the "manual" column list.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to find checkbox element and then you can get checkbox checked value by using `.prop("checked")` method.

So if you eg. want to switch checkboxes values on menu open you can use:

```
$scope.onOpen = function(e) {
    var checkboxes = $(e.item).find(".k-item:not(:has(.k-group))").find("input[type='checkbox']");
    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        var checkbox = $(checkboxes[i]);
        checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"));
    }
}
```

Updated dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/OnAXI